# Returning first value of list of tuples

Tags: list, f#, tuples

I'm learning to deal with Lists and Tuples in F# and a problem came up. I have two lists: one of names and one with names,ages.

```
let namesToFind = [ "john", "andrea" ]
let namesAndAges = [ ("john", 10); ("andrea", 15) ]
```

I'm trying to create a function that will return the first age found in namesAndAges given namesToFind. Just the first.

So far I have the following code which returns the entire tuple ("john", 10).

```
let findInList source target = 
            let itemFound = seq { for n in source do
                                    yield target |> List.filter (fun (x,y) -> x = n)  }                                
                                |> Seq.head    
            itemFound
```

I tried using fst() in the returning statement but it does not compile and gives me "This expression was expected to have type     'a * 'b     but here has type     ('c * 'd) list"

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of functions in the `Collections.List` module that can be used. Since there are no `break` or a real `return` statement in F#, it is often better to use some search function, or write a recursive loop-function. Here is an example:

```
let namesToFind = [ "john"; "andrea" ]
let namesAndAges = [ "john", 10; "andrea", 15 ]

let findInList source target =
  List.pick (fun x -> List.tryFind (fun (y,_) -> x = y) target) source

findInList namesToFind namesAndAges
```

The `findInList` function is composed of two functions from the `Collections.List` module.

- First we have the `List.tryFind predicate list` function, which returns the first item for which the given predicate function returns `true`.

  The result is in the form of an `option` type, which can take two values: `None` and `Some(x)`. It is used for functions that sometimes give no useful result.

  The signature is: `tryFind : ('T -> bool) -> 'T list -> 'T option`, where `'T` is the item type, and `('T -> bool)` is the predicate function type.

  In this case it will search trough the `target` list, looking for tuples where the first element (`y`) equals the variable `x` from the outer function.
- Then we have the `List.pick mapper list` function, which applies the `mapper`-function to each one, until the first result that is not `None`, which is returned.

  This function will not return an `option` value, but will instead throw an exception if no item is found. There is also an `option`-variant of this function named `List.tryPick`.

  The signature is: `pick : ('T -> 'U option) -> 'T list -> 'U`, where `'T` is the item type, `'U` is the result type, and `('T -> 'U option)` is the mapping function type.

  In this case it will go through the `source`-list, looking for matches in the `target` array (via `List.tryFind`) for each one, and will stop at the first match.

---

If you want to write the loops explicitly, here is how it could look:

```
let findInList source target =
  let rec loop names =
    match names with
    | (name1::xs) -> // Look at the current item in the
                     // source list, and see if there are
                     // any matches in the target list.
        let rec loop2 tuples =
          match tuples with
          | ((name2,age)::ys) ->  // Look at the current tuple in
                                  // the target list, and see if
                                  // it matches the current item.
              if name1 = name2 then
                Some (name2, age) // Found a  match!
              else
                loop2 ys          // Nothing yet; Continue looking.
          | [] -> None            // No more items, return "nothing"
        match loop2 target with           // Start the loop
        | Some (name, age) -> (name, age) // Found a match!
        | None -> loop rest               // Nothing yet; Continue looking.
    | [] -> failwith "No name found" // No more items.

  // Start the loop
  loop source
```

(`xs` and `ys` are common ways of writing lists or sequences of items)

Answer (score 3):

First let's look at your code and annotate all the types:

```
let findInList source target = 
    let itemFound =
        seq {
            for n in source do
                yield target |> List.filter (fun (x,y) -> x = n) }                                
        |> Seq.head    
    itemFound
```

The statement `yield List.Filter ...` means you're creating a sequence of lists: `seq<list<'a * 'b>>`.

The statement `Seq.head` takes the first element from your sequence of lists: `list<'a * 'b>`.

So the whole function returns a `list<'a * 'b>`, which is obviously not the right type for your function. I think you intended to write something like this:

```
let findInList source target = 
    let itemFound =
        target                               // list<'a * 'b>
        |> List.filter (fun (x,y) -> x = n)  // list<'a * 'b>
        |> Seq.head                          // 'a * 'b
    itemFound                                // function returns 'a * 'b
```

---

There are lots of ways you can get the results you want. Your code is already half way there. In place of filtering by hand, I recommend using the built in `val Seq.find : (a' -> bool) -> seq<'a> -> 'a` method:

```
let findAge l name = l |> Seq.find (fun (a, b) -> a = name) |> snd
```

Or you can try using a different data structure like a `Map<'key, 'value>`:

```
> let namesAndAges = [ ("john", 10); ("andrea", 15) ] |> Map.ofList;;

val namesAndAges : Map<string,int> = map [("andrea", 15); ("john", 10)]

> namesAndAges.["john"];;
val it : int = 10
```

If you want to write it by hand, then try this with your seq expression:

```
let findInList source target = 
    seq {
        for (x, y) in source do
            if x = target then
                yield y}
    |> Seq.head
```

Answer (score 0):

Like fst use this(below) . This way you can access all the values.

This is from F# interactive

```
let a = ((1,2), (3,4));
let b = snd (fst a);;

//interactive output below.
val a : (int * int) * (int * int) = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
val b : int = 2
```